# Why use dotenv library instead of parsing ini file?

Tags: php, ini, phpdotenv

Within PHP, *.ini files can be read by using `parse_ini_file()`. However, various frameworks (Laravel included) opt to, instead, bring in a separate library to parse an environment file.

What is the reasoning behind using this "dotenv" solution instead of ini files and the built-in PHP function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question. I've found a few mentions on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php) (search by the keyword `parse_ini_file`). The main problem, I suppose, is that `parse_ini_file` doesn't support some features, such as constants, expressions, etc. Also, I guess, some developers would like to perform such operations in OOP style.

Comment: I really appreciate of you! Also, ini parser has  some disadvantage, however there are many advantages, right? So, i still understand why dotenv, hehe. : )

Answer (score 4):

You can parse a .env file natively in PHP using [`parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).
This worked for me using Laravel .env

```
<?php
var_dump(parse_ini_file('.env', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW));
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Thanks, tried it and this puts the .env file into a PHP array for access

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. It's simply restating that it is possible to use `parse_ini_file`, which was already mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

We can access .env variables in many ways, but it is not a benefit for single project. It is better to use unified way to access these variables throughout the project any way. However, laravel is used for many projects and opting for flexibility is understandable for them.